# Why does the command-not-found handler trigger for a command that exists?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-14.04

I had a package (in this case, Docker) for which the version available in the Ubuntu repos was too old, so I added the Docker repo to my apt sources and installed the package from there.

Now, with my regular user, when I try to run it, the command-not-found handler kicks in:

```
user@host:~$ docker
The program 'docker.io' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```

Although the binary is in my path alright:

```
user@host:~$ which docker
/usr/bin/docker
```

And I do have execute permissions on it:

```
user@host:~$ /usr/bin/docker
Usage: docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND [arg...]

A self-sufficient runtime for linux containers.
....
```

I tried `hash -r`, I tried to run a new login shell, but to no avail: the command-not-found handler still kicks in.

Why does it behave like that ? is it because the package in the Ubuntu repos is called `docker.io`, but the package in the Docker repos is called just `docker` ?

Can I fix this problem without removing `command-not-found` altogether ?

EDIT: How I installed the recent version from the docker repos:

```
sudo -i
apt-get purge docker.io
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
echo "deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
apt-get update
apt-get install docker
```

EDIT2: I forgot to mention: I checked that /usr/bin/docker is not a wrapper script:

```
user@host:~$ file /usr/bin/docker
/usr/bin/docker:  ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=a5773ec80f810b977dc93bb10b4c6c6b8c2b1abd, not stripped
```

Comment: Please elaborate on _so I added the Docker repo to my apt sources and installed the package from there_. How exactly did you do those steps?

Comment: @ozbek Here you go.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 Well you found it. Something aliased docker to docker.io, removing the alias fixed it. Please make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times it's a issue of aliases, for ex. alias docker=docker.io in your bashrc/zshrc...  Also worth a check is that ver A AND  ver B are NOT installed together this often causes package and naming conflicts.